# Print content in popup in template's index file

Tags: component, plugin, jquery, javascript

[image]Hello,

I have some string values like a contract detail in one variable of template index file. Here i also attached screenshot what i am getting right now.

As you have seen in screenshot I have strings with one "Accept" button. I want all that content in popup At page load just after user gets looged in.

After Login user must be accept these terms and condition then he/she can allow to do any things else.

Or please, suggest me if any free tool is available or not?

Regards,
Urjit

code section (edited)
One code that i found is use of,

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
```

under  and Use

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_xyz&task=xyz'); ?>" class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 400, y: 400}}" >Click </a>
```

Then after click you will find popup, But it is on click event. I want on page load event. Here is reference link

Comment: please share codes you have tried for popup.

Comment: One code that i found is use of,
JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); under <head> and
Use 
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_multilevel&task=viewprice'); ?>"  

class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 400, y: 400}}" >Click </a>
Then after click you will find popup, But it is on click event. I want on page load event.
Here is reference link,
http://www.jeepstone.co.uk/2009/03/06/open-content-in-a-modal-pop-up-in-joomla/

Comment: @UrjitGandhi - Any additions such as adding code, please edit your question rather than adding them as a commment

Answer (score 1):

If your content is static, there are lot's of tools that will create a modal window from an article, module or basically any div on your page. I personally like [RokBox](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokbox) (free) for this purpose, but I haven't done auto-popup with this.

The free [Joomla Content Editor](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/jcemediabox/item/create-a-media-popup) has an option to create a popup, and among the options are auto-popup, as well as options to have the popup display only once, or each time the user visits your page.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<a href="/myvideo.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" class="jcepopup" rel="title[JCE MediaBox];caption[JCE MediaBox is great!];width[800];height[600]">My Video</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
show modal from element onload {

SqueezeBox.open($('demo-target-adopt'), {
handler: 'adopt',
size: {x: 300, y: 200}
});

}
```

reference: http://www.escope.cz/en/blog/84-how-to-use-modal-box-in-joomla
regards

Comment: This is Joomla we're talking about, not static HTML pages. This also depends on an additional script when Joomla has it's own modal methods.

Comment: Yes, above code give SyntaxError of "Invalid propertyId" in console And popup does not load. But as @lodder says it works in HTML page.

Comment: Yes correct, please check my edited answer